# Intermediate fields between $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

So I know $|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)/\mathbb{Q})| = \phi(7) = 6$

It is $\{1, \sigma_2, \dots,\sigma_6\}$ where $\sigma_a(\zeta_7) = \zeta_7^a$

Through brute force computation, I found that the subgroups are $H = \{1,\sigma_2,\sigma_2^2 \}$ and $K = \{1,\sigma_6\}$

Now what I don't get is in $H$, while the element $\alpha = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4$ is fixed by $H$, so is the element $\beta = \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^5 + \zeta_7^6.$ Since $3 = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\beta): \mathbb{Q}]$, are the two fields $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ isomorphic?

For $K$, $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$ is fixed. But so is $\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5$. However $2 =[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6):\mathbb{Q}]\neq [\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5)$ can't be an intermediate field.

Comment: Remember sum of roots of unity is $0$, so $\alpha+\beta=-1$ and similar.  Also, $\zeta_7+\zeta_7^6$ has degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$ not degree 2.

Comment: Note that $\sigma_2^2 = \sigma_4$.

Comment: @user10354138 regarding the first comment, are you trying to say that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(-\beta -1)$?

Comment: @Hawk I think user10354138 is saying a bit more than that, they are saying $\alpha=-\beta-1$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng and therefore...?

Comment: Where did you get $\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^5+\zeta^6?$

Comment: The fields $\Bbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\Bbb Q(\beta)$ are **equal**.

Comment: Okay I am back. @AnginaSeng first how did you know that $|\Bbb Q(\zeta^2+\zeta^3+\zeta^4+\zeta^5):\Bbb Q|=2?$ You surely didn't compute the min polynomial. Next, that $ \Bbb Q(\alpha) = \Bbb Q(\beta)$ from all of this? I am not seeing it

Answer (score 2):

You have done very well calculating the subgroups.

In general we have $$\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q}) = (\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z)^\times$$ which in this case is $C_6$, which you can more easily read off the fact there is 1 subgroup of index 2 and 1 subgroup of index 3.

It is useful to find a generator for $(\mathbb Z/7 \mathbb Z)^\times$. 2 usually works:

- powers of 2 mod 7: $1, 2, 4, 1, 2$ not in this case
- powers of 3 mod 7: $1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5$. So 3 is a generator for this group.

This lets us find the "periods" that are fixed under subgroups of the Galois group more easily.

Let $\sigma$ be the generator of the Galois group corresponding to 3. i.e. $\sigma \zeta_7^r = \zeta_7^{3r}$. Then we have a subgroup of index 2: $\langle \sigma^3 \rangle$ and a subgroup of index 3: $\langle \sigma^2 \rangle$.

The period sums are invariant:

- $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4$ invariant under $\sigma^2$, lies in a subfield of degree 2.
- $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$ invariant under $\sigma^3$ lies in a subfield of degree 3.

Comment: i don't think you answered my original question.

Answer (score 2):

Let

- $\alpha = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^4$
- $\beta = \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^5 + \zeta_7^6$

then consider

- $\alpha + \beta = \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5 + \zeta_7^6 = -1$
- $\alpha \cdot \beta = \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5 + \zeta_7^7 + \zeta_7^6 + \zeta_7^7 + \zeta_7^{9} + \zeta_7^7 + \zeta_7^8 + \zeta_7^{10} = \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5 + 1 + \zeta_7^6 + 1 + \zeta_7^2 + 1 + \zeta_7 + \zeta_7^3 = -1 + 3 = 2$

So you have a quadratic equation $X^2 - (\alpha + \beta) X + (\alpha \cdot \beta) = X^2 + X + 2$ that relates them. define the same quadratic subfield $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$.

---

By the Galois correspondence, there is a bijection between subfield and subgroups of the Galois group. There is exactly one subgroup of index 2 therefore there is exactly one subfield of degree 2.

---

The values

- $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$
- $\zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4$
- $\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^5$

are all conjugates, giving rise to the same cubic subfield, all root of the same minimal polynomial: $x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1$

To find them I just applied the automorphism $\sigma$ to the first.

---

Since you asked, the minpoly of $\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5$ is $x^3 + 2x^2 - x - 1$ this is a different cubic polynomial than before. But it's roots lie in the same cubic subfield. You can see this from the following computation in pari/gp:

```
? polroots(x^3 + 2*x^2 - x - 1)
%1 = [-2.2469796037174670610500097680084796213 + 0.E-38*I,
      -0.55495813208737119142219487100641048107 + 0.E-38*I, 
      0.80193773580483825247220463901489010233 + 0.E-38*I]~
? polroots(x^3 + x^2 - 2*x - 1)
%2 = [-1.8019377358048382524722046390148901023 + 0.E-38*I, 
      -0.44504186791262880857780512899358951893 + 0.E-38*I, 
      1.2469796037174670610500097680084796213 + 0.E-38*I]~
? -0.55495813208737119142219487100641048107 -0.44504186791262880857780512899358951893
%3 = -1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: How did you come up with that quadratic equation in the first place?

Comment: @Hawk  This is kind of a well known special case (found by Gauss, I think). Anyway, look at the exponents of $\zeta_7$ in $\alpha$. They are exactly the quadratic residues modulo $7$. Then $\beta=\sigma_3(\alpha)$ is the only Galois conjugate of $\alpha$. So $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the only zeros of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ etc.

Comment: So because $[\Bbb Q(\alpha ) : \Bbb Q ] = 2$ we know $\beta$ is the other root? I don't think this line of reasoning applies to the field $K$. I mean what is the conjugate to $\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6$? The minimal polynomial is a cubic.

Comment: @Hawk Added the cubic conjugates.

Comment: So what can be said about $\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5$? That's also stabilized by $K$ where does this element fit in?

Comment: "stabilized by K" doesn't make sense, did you mean stabilized by $\sigma$?

Comment: yes by $\sigma_6$.

Comment: When you say its roots lie in the same cubic subfield, are you referring to $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6)?$ It is not clear how $\zeta_7^2 + \zeta_7^3 + \zeta_7^4 + \zeta_7^5$ lies in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7 + \zeta_7^6)$

Comment: It should be clear from the computations I showed.

Comment: are you talking about the grey box? because the roots aren't there. For example, 0.8019377 isn't in the original polynomial